# How to delete all breakpoints in Bootstrap 5?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-5

I do not use breakpoints in my project.
How to delete all Bootstrap 5 breakpoints from css?

Comment: I am using SASS and grid system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply set the default (xs) breakpoint...

```
@import "functions";
@import "variables";

$grid-breakpoints: (
  xs: 0
);

@import "bootstrap";
```

Here's [a demo](https://codeply.com/p/EGSUmF4YXH), showing how *-sm, *-md *-lg, etc.. have no effect.